# Linear Arithmetic - why calling it linear?

Tags: arithmetic

This might sound like a stupid question, but I could not figure out, why Linear Arithmetic is called **linear**.

Linear Arithmetic often comes in play when talking about SMT Solving. For example, in [this PDF](http://cse-wiki.unl.edu/wiki/images/0/04/DecisionProcedure-Chapter5a.pdf) linear arithmetic is defined as formulas using $=$, $\leq$, $<$ within the atoms. Somethink like `3*x_1 + 2*x_2 ≤ 5*x_3` is a linear arithmetic formula.

Because of which property is this arithmetic called linear?

Comment: This arithmetic preserves the linearity of the atoms.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity

Answer (score 5):

It seems that *linear* in that document is related to *linear programming*, which is optimization with linear constraints.

Comment: Yes, a point made explicit in Sec. 5.1.1 of the PDF, Solvers for Linear Arithmetic.  Apparently the term linear arithmetic is being used to pose (first order polynomial) constraints, whose satisfiability then constitute decision problems.

Answer (score 0):

A function $F(x)$ is linear when $F(ax+by)=aF(x)+bF(y)$. This means that solutions to $F(x)=0$ are linear spaces and solutions to $F(x)\le 0$ are half spaces. The point, here, is that all your formulas are constructed to be linear.

Comment: It seems more apt to construe "linear" as referring to first-order polynomials, rather than to linearity of a function on a vector space.  Affine functions, in particular, are allowed in this linear arithmetic.

Comment: Well, but why first order polynomials are called linear, after all?