# What is the difference between "linear algebra" and "linear arithmetic"?

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic, satisfiability

I am curious to figure out the difference between linear algebra and linear arithmetic. By linear arithmetic I mean the one is usually used in SMT(satisfiability modulo theory) context as LRA (linear real arithmetic).

Comment: See the post [Linear Arithmetic - why calling it linear?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435326/linear-arithmetic-why-calling-it-linear)

Comment: [Linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra) "is the branch of mathematics concerned with the study of vectors, vector spaces (also called linear spaces), linear transformations (also called linear maps), and systems of linear equations."

Comment: Thus, no "deep connection" here : only the prominent role of "linear" functions, formulas in both.